# How can I specify that I want C++0x in Makefile.am?

Tags: c++11, automake

Currently my project has the following simple tree:

```
./Makefile.am
./configure.ac
./README
./src/main.cpp
./src/Makefile.am
./bin
```

I'm trying to following the following tutorial:

http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Hello-World

How can I instruct configure.ac to use the C++0x extensions?  In particular, what if the hello-world line in main.cpp file is as follows:

```
cout << ([] () {return "Hello, World!";}) () << endl;
```

Issuing "make" results in an error.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? If it is GCC you need 4.6 or later for lambdas, then it should be a case of modifying the makefile to add a flag to put the comiler in c++0X mode, either --std=c++0x or --std=gnu++0x depending on whether or not you want the GNU dialect of c++0x.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use C++11 features with Autoconf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987952/how-to-use-c11-features-with-autoconf)

Comment: @awoodland, I tried your suggestiom from the other thread.  I get the following error:  "./configure: line 2962: syntax error near unexpected token `-std=c++0x,'" after which the erroneous line highlighted is as follows: AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG(-std=c++0x, CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -std=c++0x").  The line before that says "checking dependency style of g++... gcc3."  I would think that is the problem.  But I have GCC 4.6.2 installed, and it is the default version of GCC.  (Running gcc -v returns version 4.6.2.)

Comment: @Shredderroy - The compiler version doesn't matter much for autoconf stuff, but you do need to quote -std=c++0x using `[ ]`, exactly like I did in my example. You might be interested in [Autoconf quoting](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.68/html_node/M4-Quotation.html#M4-Quotation) if you're new to autotools.

Comment: Just in case it matters, I'm using Fedora 16, with KDE 4.7.3.

Comment: @awoodland, I did quote it in the source file.  The contents of the first square bracket are by themselves, those of the second square bracket are in quotation marks, just like in the example.  But the error message does not show the quotation marks.

Comment: These are the exact lines:  AC_PROG_CXX, and then AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-std=c++0x], [CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -std=c++0x"]).

Comment: Looks like you don't have a definition of `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG` available then - you need that from the autoconf macro archive, either locally in your source tree, or system-wide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autotools check for C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909347/autotools-check-for-c11)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using gcc (looks like you are) then from the [libstdc++ manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/backwards.html) they have autoconf examples for checking c++ base language features:

```
# AC_COMPILE_STDCXX_OX
AC_DEFUN([AC_COMPILE_STDCXX_0X], [
  AC_CACHE_CHECK(if g++ supports C++0x features without additional flags,
  ac_cv_cxx_compile_cxx0x_native,
  [AC_LANG_SAVE
  AC_LANG_CPLUSPLUS
  AC_TRY_COMPILE([
  template <typename T>
    struct check
    {
      static_assert(sizeof(int) <= sizeof(T), "not big enough");
    };

    typedef check<check<bool>> right_angle_brackets;

    int a;
    decltype(a) b;

    typedef check<int> check_type;
    check_type c;
    check_type&& cr = c;],,
  ac_cv_cxx_compile_cxx0x_native=yes, ac_cv_cxx_compile_cxx0x_native=no)
  AC_LANG_RESTORE
  ])

  AC_CACHE_CHECK(if g++ supports C++0x features with -std=c++0x,
  ac_cv_cxx_compile_cxx0x_cxx,
  [AC_LANG_SAVE
  AC_LANG_CPLUSPLUS
  ac_save_CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS"
  CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -std=c++0x"
  AC_TRY_COMPILE([
  template <typename T>
    struct check
    {
      static_assert(sizeof(int) <= sizeof(T), "not big enough");
    };

    typedef check<check<bool>> right_angle_brackets;

    int a;
    decltype(a) b;

    typedef check<int> check_type;
    check_type c;
    check_type&& cr = c;],,
  ac_cv_cxx_compile_cxx0x_cxx=yes, ac_cv_cxx_compile_cxx0x_cxx=no)
  CXXFLAGS="$ac_save_CXXFLAGS"
  AC_LANG_RESTORE
  ])

  AC_CACHE_CHECK(if g++ supports C++0x features with -std=gnu++0x,
  ac_cv_cxx_compile_cxx0x_gxx,
  [AC_LANG_SAVE
  AC_LANG_CPLUSPLUS
  ac_save_CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS"
  CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -std=gnu++0x"
  AC_TRY_COMPILE([
  template <typename T>
    struct check
    {
      static_assert(sizeof(int) <= sizeof(T), "not big enough");
    };

    typedef check<check<bool>> right_angle_brackets;

    int a;
    decltype(a) b;

    typedef check<int> check_type;
    check_type c;
    check_type&& cr = c;],,
  ac_cv_cxx_compile_cxx0x_gxx=yes, ac_cv_cxx_compile_cxx0x_gxx=no)
  CXXFLAGS="$ac_save_CXXFLAGS"
  AC_LANG_RESTORE
  ])

  if test "$ac_cv_cxx_compile_cxx0x_native" = yes ||
     test "$ac_cv_cxx_compile_cxx0x_cxx" = yes ||
     test "$ac_cv_cxx_compile_cxx0x_gxx" = yes; then
    AC_DEFINE(HAVE_STDCXX_0X,,[Define if g++ supports C++0x features. ])
  fi
])
```

You could probably try to put a lambda in there if you wanted.  Then with HAVE_STDCXX_0X in hand you could set --std=c++0x appropriately.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks a lot for that extended response.  I will now try it out, and report back

Comment: Unless you are the maintainer of autoconf, you should not define a macro with the name beginning "AC_".  Autoconf reserves that namespace for itself.