# Where do I put additional autotool macros?

Tags: autotools

emsr's answer to this question: [How can I specify that I want C++0x in Makefile.am?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585110/how-can-i-specify-that-i-want-c0x-in-makefile-am) is the solution to a problem I have. No I have a new one:

I put the macro definition into m4/check.m4 and change my configure.ac accordingly:

```
AC_INIT([CppSs], [0.1], [brinkmann@hlrs.de])
m4_include([m4/check.m4])
LT_INIT

AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/main.cc])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile src/Makefile])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_CC

# ...

# Check for C++0x features
AC_COMPILE_STDCXX_OX
AC_HEADER_STDCXX_11

AC_OUTPUT
```

Now when I run `autoreconf -v` I get these messages (tried -fiv also):

```
configure.ac:43: warning: AC_COMPILE_STDCXX_11 is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd 
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:606: AS_IF is expanded from... 
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2032: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from... 
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2053: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from... m4/cppss.
m4:90: AC_HEADER_STDCXX_11 is expanded from...
```

./configure yields:

```
...
./configure: line 16234: AC_COMPILE_STDCXX_OX: command not found
./configure: line 16235: AC_COMPILE_STDCXX_11: command not found
...
```

What am I missing?

Thanks, Steffen

Comment: Is there a typo in the question?  You m4_include([m4/check.m4]), but you write that the macro definition is in m4/foo.m4.

Comment: @William Pursell: Yes, it was a typo, thanks for pointing out. Corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself... It was a mixture of several typos (`0` instead of `O` and alike) and mistakes in the order of putting the macros in the `configure.ac`. Also, I found out, that if it's just a few macros, it's easier to put them in a file called `acinclude.m4` in the same directory as `configure.ac` and get rid of the

```
m4_include([m4/check.m4])
```

And there is an error in the [libstdc++ manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/backwards.html) in the part at the bottom of the page where the c++11 features are checked, as (at least in gcc) there is no compiler option `-std=c++11`. It should be `-std=c++0x`.

Cheers, Steffen

Comment: using acinclude.m4 is discouraged.  See the documentation for aclocal.

Comment: Another option is to make the macro available to all packages by putting it in the directory in which aclocal looks.  You can invoke aclocal with --print-ac-dir to determine which directory that is.  Also, look for 'dirlist' in the aclocal documentation.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: thanks for the advice. I want to distribute the test along with the software so I opted to put the macros again in m4/check.m4 and ac_include this file.

Comment: If you put the .m4 file in $(aclocal --print-ac-dir), aclocal will copy it into aclocal.m4 and it will wind up in the distribution tarball.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I see... thanks again, maybe that IS the best option than ;)