# Autotools check for C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, autotools, autoconf

I use `AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_0X`(can look on autoconf-archive) to check for c++11 capabilities of the compiler. It correctly determines that `-std=c++0x` required, but does not add it to `CXXFLAGS`. I took a look at the macro source and it actually checks but then restores previous flags.

What should I do to get `CXXFLAGS` set to be able to compile c++11 source?

Just adding `-std=c++0x` to `AM_CXXFLAGS` is not nice solution, because I'd like to put the burden of making the compiler compile in C++11 mode on the autoconf developers, not me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What you're looking for has already been made as [`AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.html), part of [autoconf-archive](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/). It will add the required option to the environment (formerly through `CXXFLAGS`, now through `CXX`) and error out if no C++11 support is available.

Comment: `configure.ac:15: error: AC_LANG_ASSERT: current language is not C++:  C
../../lib/autoconf/lang.m4:156: AC_LANG_ASSERT is expanded from...
m4/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4:48: AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11 is expanded from...
configure.ac:15: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: /usr/bin/autom4te failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1`

I put it just after `AC_PROG_CXX`. What I do wrong?

Comment: Sorry for long comment. I found no way to format it. Well, I added `AC_LANG([C++])` just before `AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11`, but I assumed it is called by `AC_PROG_CXX`.

Comment: @illusionoflife `AC_PROG_CXX` shouldn't do that because it would mess up configure scripts that have both C and C++ checks. Most autoconf checks rely on C. Adding AC_LANG as you have is the right thing to do.

Comment: How is this macro installed? Does it come with autoconf itself? If I add this macro to my configure.ac the -std compilerflags are not added. I can also only add the macro without any arguments (i.e. as AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11() .. the documentation on autoconf-archive states that it should accept 2 parameters but when I try that it bails out with a syntax error when I run configure.

Comment: @Lieuwe Please be more specific than "a syntax error". :) Like most macros, this one should end up in your project's m4 directory, and your project should be set up to use that directory as the option argument to the `-I` option.

Comment: I can't be a lot more specific: "./configure: line 2308: syntax error near unexpected token `ext,mandatory'" for instance

Comment: question here: should ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4 set CXXFLAGS (as it does) or AM_CXXFLAGS?  The problem is that I cannot do a user-level setting of CXXFLAGS on the make line, for example: make CXXFLAGS="-g -O0 -Wall" fails because the -std=c++11 flag gets lost.

Comment: @markgalassi The latest version doesn't clobber CXXFLAGS, it now clobbers CXX instead. I add `CXX$1_FLAGS=$switch` and `AC_SUBST(CXX$1_FLAGS)` to have it instead set e.g. `CXX11_FLAGS`

Comment: To get it to work, I also installed autoconf-archive, which is where the macro 'lives', as far as I understand it.

Comment: @MicroVirus Right, that's why I linked to documentation from autoconf-archive, but it's good to mention it explicitly. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can compile a simple code and set a variable based the outcome of your compilation

```
DIALECT="-std=c++14"
echo 'int main() {return 0;}' > ./log.cpp && $CXX -std=c++14 ./log.cpp || $DIALECT="no"

if test $DILAECT = no; then
    AC_MSG_ERROR([c++ compiler does not support c++14])
else
    echo $DILAECT
fi
```