# C++11 support in GNU automake

Tags: c++, autotools

I'm trying to port buildsystem of my project to GNU autotools. The code need to be compiled with `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` flag. I want my configure script to check if compiler supports C++11 or not. I tried adding `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-std=c++0x], [CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -std=c++0x"])` to `configure.ac` file but `configure` fails with this error:

```
 ...
./configure: line 2732: syntax error near unexpected token `-std=c++0x,'
./configure: line 2732: `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG(-std=c++0x, CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -std=c++0x")'
```

Comment: Didn't you forget to call aclocal before autoconf?

Comment: @v154c1 I never call that! I call `automake` then `autoreconf`. I tested it now. calling `aclocal` doesn't help

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/11909347/243712

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully there will be more comprehensive support for C++11 in future autoconf releases. In the mean time, I use a C++11 source test from `ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4` in the [GNU autoconf archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/):

```
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_LANG_PUSH([C++])

AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_SOURCE(
  [[template <typename T>
    struct check
    {
      static_assert(sizeof(int) <= sizeof(T), "not big enough");
    };

    typedef check<check<bool>> right_angle_brackets;

    int a;
    decltype(a) b;

    typedef check<int> check_type;
    check_type c;
    check_type&& cr = static_cast<check_type&&>(c);]])],,
  AC_MSG_FAILURE(['$CXX $CXXFLAGS' does not accept ISO C++11]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting seems to come from `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG` not being expanded in your `configure` script. You can verify whether it is expanded by grepping `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG` in `configure`. If the grep finds it there, then it is not expanded.

You can also check it by looking into file `aclocal.m4`, where `aclocal` should copy it's definition.

The definition of this macro is not included in basic `autoconf` package, but in the `autoconf` archives. So you're probably missing this package. (Exact name of the package may differ between distributions, it is `sys-devel/autoconf-archive` in Gentoo and it seems to be `autoconf-archive` in Debian and Ubuntu).

Comment: You're right. It's as is in `configure`. `cat ./configure | grep AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG` result is: `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG(-std=c++0x, CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -std=c++0x")`

Comment: Have you fixed this? If yes, how did you do it?

Comment: @soroush I fixed it using `CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -std=c++0x"` at the end of my configure.in (configure.ac) file, right before `AC_OUTPUT`. Otherwise the compile parameters will not be placed in the correct order. (in my case)

Comment: @Qsiris I want my configure script to check that platform supports C++11 or not. Brett's solution works fine, though I'm not satisfied yet. There should be a macro for that