# Automatically select a C++11-compatible g++ version in the Makefile

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

The problem:

2 version of g++ installed on a computer running Ubuntu 12.04. They are the versions 4.6 and 5.2.

I have to compile a C++11 program using a Makefile. If I use g++ as compiler it calls automatically the version 4.6, it does not support c++11 so the compilation fails. I've followed a tutorial online, so that now if I call g++ it calls automatically the version 5.2 and now it works.

I find this solution not so good, since it works only on my PC. Is there a way to recognize in the Makefile if the default g++ version support C++11 and, in case not, switch to a more recent version?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd set my CC and CXX environment variables before invoking make on the command line. You can then use CC and CXX in your makefile to make it work. The shell scripts cc and cxx ( / c++ ) use those environment variables.

Comment: Have you considered configuring the makefiles with autotools? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909347/autotools-check-for-c11) tells you how to create a check for C++11 capabilities.

Comment: Another great option is CMake. It checks for different compiler capabilities by attempting to compile small test programs.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way to recognize in the Makefile if the default g++ version support C++11 and, in case not, switch to a more recent version?

You can certainly detect the version of the default compiler available in `PATH` in your makefile. However, where do you search for another version?

The standard approach is to let the user specify the C compiler through `CC` and C++ compiler through `CXX` make variables, e.g.:  `make CC=/path/to/my/gcc CXX=/path/to/my/g++`.

Comment: In this way the user, before calling `make`, should call  
    `make CC=/path/to/my/gcc CXX=/path/to/my/g++`
right?

Comment: Not _before_ calling `make`. _When_ calling make pass extra variables to it, see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding

Comment: I have to say that, if it's possible and not too complicated for you to pass custom arguments to make calls on different platforms, then this is the answer you want. It's the least intrusive, and most flexible.

Answer (score 4):

You can always select which gcc to use while invoking `make`

```
make CXX=/gcc/path/of/your/choice
```

otherwise you can detect `gcc` version using

```
ifdef CXX
     GCC_VERSION = $(shell $(CXX) -dumpversion)                                                                                               
else
     GCC_VERSION = $(shell g++ -dumpversion)
endif
```

in `Makefile` and while using, you can test if your `gcc` is >=4.6

```
ifeq ($(shell expr $(GCC_VERSION) '>=' 4.6), 1)
```

UPDATE: newer gcc needs -dumpfullversion together (icx is the CC from Intel OneAPI)

```
$ icx -dumpversion
  14.0.0
$ gcc -dumpversion
  9    
$ icx -dumpfullversion -dumpversion
  14.0.0
$ gcc -dumpfullversion -dumpversion
  9.3.1
```

Comment: You should assign default value `CXX=g++` in the makefile. `make CXX=...` overrides your assignment. This way you do not need this conditional at all. Just `GCC_VERSION = $(shell $(CXX) -dumpversion)` one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

One very simple way is to use conditional statements in your makefile, and go for versions which you know are compatible, and only use the default `gcc` as a fallback. Here's a basic example:

```
CXX=g++

ifeq (/usr/bin/g++-4.9,$(wildcard /usr/bin/g++-4.9*))
    CXX=g++-4.9
# else if... (a list of known-to-be-ok versions)
endif
```

The other, more robust method, is to generate your makefile using a script that checks for capabilities using test compilations, kind of like what `./configure` usually does. I really don't mean to recommend `autotools`, though.

Comment: Thank you! I think that this will solve the problem!
Why don't you recommend autotools?

Comment: @stefano1 It's a lot of boilerplate. Not all projects need it, and most can do with a much simpler (and often better) build system. By the way, google "tup".

Comment: @YamMarcovic make is simple and powerful, but has got a steep learning curve, IMO. I have seen different build systems over the years based on CMake, tup, premake, ninja, etc.. They were not better or faster than my non-recursive makes.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I work with the AOSP, which uses a non-recursive make. It's horrible at such large scales. For small to medium-sized projects I also used a non-recursive make, but once I switched to tup (and learned how to use it idiomatically) I didn't look back. P.S. CMake and ninja aren't really comparable to make or tup.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin At any rate, however, I talked about `autotools`, not make.

Comment: @YamMarcovic I am not going to argue, that is a battle one cannot win :)

Answer (score 1):

The thing to do is build your Makefile to use as many implicit rules as possible. By default compilation uses various environment variables.

The variable `$(CXX)` is the `C++` compiler command and defaults to `g++` on `Linux` systems. So clanging `CXX` to a different compiler executable will change the compiler for all implicit compile commands.

When you write *explicit* rules use the same variable that the implicit rules use. So instead of this:

```
program: program.cpp
    g++ -o program program.cpp
```

Do this:

```
program: program.cpp
    $(CXX) -o program program.cpp
```

Other variables you should use are:

```
CPPFLAGS = -Iinclude
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++14 -g3 -O0
```

Those are for pre-processing flags `CPPFLAGS` and compiler flags `CXXFLAGS` and library linking flags `LDLIBS`.

Using the default environment variables allows the person compiling the project the freedom to control the compilation for their desired environment.

See the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables)

Answer (score 0):

You can check in your source code the gcc version and abort compilation if you don't like it. [Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) is how it works:

```
/* Test for GCC > 4.6 */
#if !(__GNUC__ > 3 && __GNUC_MINOR__ > 6)
#error gcc above version 4.6 required!
#endif
```

Comment: He is looking for a way to detect in makefile, Your answer will work on c/c++ files

Comment: @Deleisha, indeed. Yet, most users have only one - the latest possible - gcc version installed and "selecting" a gcc installation isn't a really good idea. Drop the compilation and let the user handle the situation.

Comment: Yes, What I was trying to say was, He is asking for a way to do in `Makefile`. Your approach is for detecting in c/c++ files

Comment: @Vorac Can you edit your answer. There is missing enclosing bracket and second exclamation mark before minor version check.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
project(test)

if (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION} LESS 5.0)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "You need a version of gcc > 5.0")
endif (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION} LESS 5.0)

add_executable(test test.cpp)
```

Comment: I guess, He is looking for a way in `makefile`, your is `cmake` recipe

Comment: You are right. I didn't read correctly and thought he was using cmake. who uses makefile without cmake or some other building tool these days?

Comment: The reason is that the compilation is really really simple. It would suffice a simple `g++ main.cpp -O3 -std=c++11` since all the classes are templates.
Do you think that it's better to use cmake also in this case?

Comment: No you are right. If it's that simple is an overkill to use cmake to generate a makefile. I was just being sarcastic.